# Memory allocation for pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have a following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char * test()
{
char * rt="hello";
return rt;

}

void main()
{
printf("\n %s \n", test());
}
```

here, it correctly prints hello while if rt is not a constant pointer like char rt[]="hello" it prints garbage. My understanding, in latter stack gets freed when function returns from test but what happens with above case? where does the memory for char *rt is allocated?

Extending above part, If I try to do char rt[]="hello" and if i try rt="hrer" it throws error while with char *rt="hello" it works fine but we can not change particular character in a string with later case. Please help me to understand it. Thanks.

Comment: can someone help me understand why the downvotes on the OP question?

Comment: @JohnJesus; Because OP had not searched SO correctly before asking this question, there is already a question with 4 answers. And also title of question is far from the question.

Comment: Whatever book or tutorial told you to use `void main()`, find a better one. `int main(void)` is correct.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Could you please explain why int main is correct and former is not correct ?

Comment: @RoshanC.: Because the C standard says so. `main` can be defined as `int main(void)` or as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent. Other *implementation-defined* forms may be permitted, but there's rarely any reason to use anything other than those two. (It's a different story for freestanding implementations, basically embedded systems.) The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is an excellent resource; see questions 11.12a and 11.12b.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for the link. you got my upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string `"hello"` is what is called a **string literal**.  It resides in what is called the **data segment** of your program, which is a region of memory.  Any other string literals throughout your code are put there as well.  This region is loaded once, and never destroyed.

So, your pointer `rt` is pointing somewhere into that region.

But, if you declare `char rt[] = "hello"`, you are declaring an array named `rt[]` on the stack and the array is 6 bytes long (hello + null terminator).  When the function returns, the stack is freed, so, this memory will be invalid.

Some more information on string literals are here: [C String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)

Comment: For Christ sake why the screen name John Jesus?

Comment: @EdHeal; Ya. Good question.

Comment: @edheal hehe, that's my real name.

Comment: @JohnJesus - Are you a Muslim? Surely with the surname Jesus you are Jewish

Comment: @EdHeal; Why do you think moslims uses `jesus` as surname?

Comment: @haccks - Tongue in check humour. Anyway Jesus was a Jew and they do not seem to like Muslims

Comment: @haccks - There was no Christianity before Jesus. He was born into the Jewish faith. Guess he was a crafty Jew that wanted a slice of the action and made up another religion from all the others kicking around the Mediterranean at the time (see . Yes I am an Atheist and I think religion is just a con to control people.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39304/discussion-between-haccks-and-ed-heal)

Answer (score 1):

The string `Hello` gets set into the read portion of the executable part of the program. The function returns a pointer to that.

The use of an array (in the second case) means that it gets copied onto the stack.

End of the function it gets zapped - hence garbage